# Множественное число слова «контроль»

Tags: орфография, существительные, множественное-число

Существует ли множественное число слова **контроль**? В аудиторских заключениях часто употребляется множественное число. Насколько это допустимо?

Answer (score 3):

В *Новом словаре русского языка Ефремовой*:
[контроль](https://slovar.cc/rus/efremova/171788.html), м.

1. Проверка кого-либо, чего-либо, наблюдение за кем-либо, чем-либо с целью проверки.
2. Учреждение, организация, осуществляющие такие проверки.
3. Место при входе в театре, кинотеатре и т. п., где контролеры проверяют билеты.
4. *разг.* то же, что контролеры.

Действительно, некоторые [словари](https://slovar.cc/enc/slovarik/1805981.html) указывают, что множественного числа у слова нет. Но в *Большом современном толковом словаре русского языка* и в словаре Ефремовой такая пометка отсутствует.
Думаю, что в некоторых случаях употребление "контроли" допустимо.
Это могут быть ситуации, при описывании которых автору нужно **сделать акцент на количестве** контролирующих организаций или пунктов контроля и **сложностях**, связанных с этим.

*Но нам все же пришлось проделать все положенные процедуры, **пройти контроли**, дождаться багажа, сесть в такси и поехать по жутким пробкам в самое сердце древней столицы* ([А. Кулик. На виниле](https://books.google.ee/books?id=HwBPDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT286&lpg=PT286&dq=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8&source=bl&ots=YpQJOqYeQZ&sig=ACfU3U26CgI2CnZQtT2A5v72v8pvvqEAVA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiTscmR-PTgAhUnmYsKHaJACAs4ChDoATAKegQIARAB#v=onepage&q=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8&f=false)).

А так как мое дело всепланетное, то вам придется решать соединенными **Контролями** Юга и Севера ― итого двадцать один человек, помимо вас… [И. А. Ефремов. Туманность Андромеды (1956)]

Answer (score 1):

Словари не запрещают использование множественного числа. В художественной и специальной литературе тоже нередко встречается. Например:

> Это позволило объединить все контроли. (Доклады АН СССР)
>
> Надо пройти через три двора, через караулы и контроли... (Михаил
>   Кольцов)

Answer (score 0):

Нормативных документов по грамматике (формообразованию слов) русского языка не существует. Поэтому все возможно и все допустимо или недопустимо.
Ефремова, Кольцов, Кулик, АН... можно еще на Петрова с Башировым сослаться и все будет обосновано просто ссылками на мыслимые авторитеты.
Одни считают так, другие эдак. По мне так не существует формы "контроли" и производных, таких как "нормоконтроли", "партконтроли", "термоконтроли","бюджетные контроли", "бухгалтерские контроли" - я так решил.

Comment: Хорошее мнение и, главное, убедительное: "я так решил".

Answer (score 0):

Человек, хоть и выразился достаточно категорично, абсолютно прав. Множественное число от слова КОНТРОЛЬ звучит крайне коряво, неестественно и неблагозвучно для русского языка. И то, что кто-то где-то когда-то употребил это слово во множественном числе, совершенно не говорит о том, что это абсолютно правильно, и именно так и следует говорить!